# what does System.out.println(pic.getId()); do? (and it's not working on my computer)

Tags: java, javafx, filechooser

so I was reading Java tutorials on this website: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JavaFX/0555__JavaFX_FileChooser.htm

and this code:

```
FileChooser fileChooser1 = new FileChooser();
fileChooser1.setTitle("Save Image");
System.out.println(pic.getId());
File file = fileChooser1.showSaveDialog(stage);
System.out.println(file);
```

was for saving files. But this code doens't work at all on my Eclipse (and I use Mac), I have no idea what pic.getId() is supposed to do. I googled everywhere and couldn't get the answer.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "doens't work at all"? Does it not compile, does it throw an exception, does it print out a value you don't understand? It would also help if you'd include the declaration of `pic` within the question, rather than us having to refer to a web page.

Comment: Well, `pic` isn't declared anywhere.

Comment: Given that the tutorial doesn't give any more information, I'd just put this down to being a really poor tutorial.

Comment: @Daisy Shipton: when I wrote that code and ran it, it showed the dialog and popup windows for saving but when I actually saved the file, it didn't actually save anything. I double checked which directory it was supposed to save and everything. the code itself did not give any compile error nor any runtime error.

Comment: @Jay: well yes, pic wasn't declared anywhere but the weird thing is 'other tutorials' from other websites and authors also had 'pic' variable in the exact same manner but still without any context/explanation. I am very confused by this.

Comment: I'm not sure what dialog you're talking about, but normally in Eclipse you create a file, then edit it and save it. At that point I'd expect to see a compile-time error. But fundamentally, this isn't a standalone piece of code you can run - and I'd steer clear of that tutorial if you can, given the lack of explanation.

Comment: Just ignore&remove it. Probably this was copied from some code that printed out the `id` of the button containing the handler for debugging or something like this. Other tutorials were probably based on the code for this one. I recommend choosing a different tutorial anyways since it uses the `VBoxBuilder` class that was deprecated&removed from the API. BTW: `FileChooser` only provides functionality to choose a file you can write info to. It does not write the file at all. You need to do this from your own code.

Comment: Should I add that the use of the `VBoxBuilder` in the tutorial is not even beneficial for the code readability? You could achieve the exact same effect using the constructor: `VBox vBox = new VBox(buttonLoad);`

Comment: @fabian Thank you for the tip because I wrongfully assumed that FileChooser would also actually write and save the file.

Answer (score 0):

The System.out.println(pic.getId()); is doesn't matter. Since it is only a debug information. So you can comment this line. And you want the codes work, you  should follow this example which can be found in the tutorial.

```
public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {
        FileChooser fileChooser1 = new FileChooser();
        fileChooser1.setTitle("Save Image");
        //System.out.println(pic.getId());
        File file = fileChooser1.showSaveDialog(primaryState);
        System.out.println(file);
    }
}
```